# Comparing array element to the next array and starting over when the element is new

Tags: java, arrays, oop

So I have a  similar data like this

```
a
a
a
a
b
b
c
d
d
d
```

I want to build a program where the program can count how many number of each string exists in my document. So, from the data above, I want the result to be a = 4 b = 2 c =1 d = 3. The data has been sorted, so I think first I have to make a loop where I compare the first data to the second. If it matches, then the count variable will increment. If it doesn't, it'l assume that it's a new data, so the count is reset to 0. The problem is I don't have the result as I wanted. Here's my code so far.

```
 String[] nextLine;
        int count=0;
        nextLine = reader.readNext();
        String current= nextLine[0];
        while(reader.readNext()!=null){
            nextLine = reader.readNext();
            if(current.matches(nextLine[0])){
                count++;
            }else{
                System.out.println("data = "+current+" total = "+count);
                count=0;
                current = nextLine[0];
            }

        }
```

reader is the object I created to read from my document.
I am sorry if you don't really get what I mean. I have difficulties phrasing this (English isn't my first language), just drop a comment if you don't understand something. Thanks in advance.

For you asking what kind of result I get, this is what I got

```
data = 2013-07-01 total = 2199
data = 2013-07-02 total = 0
data = 2013-07-01 total = 1
data = 2013-07-02 total = 0
data = 2013-07-01 total = 0
data = 2013-07-02 total = 0
data = 2013-07-01 total = 0
data = 2013-07-02 total = 0
........
data = 2013-08-09 total = 0
data = 2013-08-12 total = 1
data = 2013-08-11 total = 0
data = 2013-08-12 total = 7
data = 2013-08-11 total = 0
data = 2013-08-12 total = 0
data = 2013-08-11 total = 0
data = 2013-08-10 total = 0
data = 2013-08-11 total = 0
data = 2013-08-12 total = 0
data = 2013-08-11 total = 1
data = 2013-08-12 total = 1
data = 2013-08-11 total = 1
data = 2013-08-12 total = 0
data = 2013-08-10 total = 0
data = 2013-08-12 total = 0
```

Yes, it's a date, but I saved it in String data type so I don't think it should be a problem. And for anyone who has tried to answer my question, thank you very much, but the result I got is not so different than what I got using my code above. So I still have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: What is the result you are currently getting? Also how are the letters stored in the document?

Comment: @AnnaRG you can never count frequency of every string using a single variable count.

Comment: @AnnaRG Are you aware of TreeMap or HashMap?

Comment: What type is `reader`? What does `readNext()` return?

Comment: Are you using a csvReader, or which Reader are you using?

Comment: what is your reader?

Comment: @Dante You can, if the data is sorted and you are just printing the frequency as you finish each run.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ok,its sorted,then yes we can.

Comment: yes I am using csvReader, so I suppose readNext() is a method from them? I am sorry I forgot to specify that before

Comment: And I don't know if it's really necessary to use TreeMap or HashMap here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will work if the data is arranged in the text file like so:

```
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
c
```

My answer uses the [Scanner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and hopefully you find it helpful. I just hard coded the scanner to read from a file called stack.txt.This was used for my own tests, so be sure to replace stack.txt with the name of your file.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new File ("stack.txt"));
int charFrequency = 0;
String value = "";
while (scanner.hasNext()){
    String tempValue = scanner.next();
    if ("".equals(value)) {
        value = tempValue;
        charFrequency ++;
    }
    else if (value.equals(tempValue)) {
        charFrequency ++;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Data: " +value+" Count: "+charFrequency);
        value = tempValue;  
        charFrequency = 1;
    }
}
System.out.println("Data :" +value+" Count: "+charFrequency);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer. But I don't understand the "" part. Am I supposed to replace that with the value I should be looking for, or just leave it like that. Because I tried your code but it doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried your code on a smaller document (contains less than 20 lines of data) and it works! But I have no idea why it doesn't want to work on my original document (it's a csv file which has over 1.7 millions lines of data, but only 20 MB in size though), so do you think the size of my document may be the cause of the problem?

Comment: My bad, I just checked my document and I just found there's something wrong with it. Now I know the problem, and there's definitely nothing wrong with your code, the problem is entirely on me. So thank you very much! Ok I already posted 3 comments to myself so far it seems like I am talking to myself now lol.

Comment: It's okay. The "".equals(value) checks to see if value is equal to an empty string. A.K.A. if value doesn't have a value assigned to it or is uninitialized

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me your strategy and algorithm are correct - but you need to count the first one - where you are going count=0 you have already read through one so you need to go count=1 instead.

You also have a few other problems:
The readline in the while throws away it's result so you only read every second line.
The readline at the front can cause losses- rather set the current to something invalid (0?) and just go intot he loop from there.

There is another (perhaps better) solution using HashSet which you might consider.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a map and fill it with strings as keys, and integers as values. so you can ask if the map contains the next key already, if yes count up the value, if not put in a new key and set the value to 1.

something like that:

```
List<String> asList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "a");
HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (String s : asList) {
  if(map.containsKey(s))
    map.put(s, (int) map.get(s) + 1);
  else
    map.put(s, 1);
}

for (Object s : map.keySet()) {
     System.out.println(map.get(s));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just try this:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List asList = Arrays.asList("a","b","a","b","a","a",...);
    Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(asList);
    for(String s: mySet){

     System.out.println(s + " " +Collections.frequency(asList,s));

    }
```

}

Comment: Doesn't explain to the OP what his problems are nor does this answer express why this solution is better (which it is) nor does it discuss that this strategy works on UNSORTED data